# How to refresh fusion layer and filter displayed markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to use the Fusion layer in Google maps to display the locations and status of routers as markers, where the colour of the marker tells you what its status is. As a result the data in the Fusion table changes frequently, which means the map has to refresh itself in order to display the changes in the table

I managed to refresh the layer using the following code in javascript:

```
function refresh()
{
  layer.setOptions({
            query: {
                select: '\'location\'',
                from: dbloc,
                where: "location != " + (-1 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)).toString()
            },
            styleId: styleNr,
            map: map
   }); 

}
```

This function is called every ten seconds and works perfectly when displaying all of the markers on the map, but when I want to filter the markers based on another column (in this case the column for status) nothing happens.

I tried adding the filter for the status like so:

```
where: "location != " + (-1 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)).toString() + " and " + "status = " + selectedStatus
```

I also tried putting them in an array and passing it to the query:

```
var refreshClause = "location != " + (-1 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)).toString();
var statusClause = "status = " + selectedStatus;

where: [refreshClause, statusClause]
```

Sadly both of these don't work.

If I use the criteria to filter by status without the criteria needed to refresh the fusion layer, the markers are filtered properly by the given status. The only problem then is that the displayed markers no longer change if the data in the Fusion table changes. So, if I'm displaying markers with status 1 and change one the markers to status 2, that marker remains on the map instead of disapearing.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there another way? It is important that I can filter the displayed markers since there will be a lot of them and the map has to refresh itself in order to display the current status of the router.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your FusionTable look like?  Is "status" a column?

Comment: Status is a column in the FusionTable, it contains the numbers 1, 2 or 3.  1 is online, 2 is offline and 3 is unknown. Other than that the FusionTable has the columns Id, Customer_id and Location.

Comment: Is it "Status" or "status" (column names are case sensitive).

Comment: "status" with a lowercase s

Comment: maybe some kind of caching is active there, do you get the correct markers when you wait a while?

Comment: @Dr.Molle If, for example i'm filtering status 1 and change one of the markers from status 1 to status 2, the marker doesn't disappear. If i zoom out or in it disappears, but it still reapears when returning to the first zoom level.

Comment: this really sounds like a caching-issue related to the tiles(although it shouldn't be possible because of the random clause)

Comment: @Dr.Molle when i only use the random clause, refreshing works fine. The problem starts when I want to add `"status = " + selectedStatus` to the clause. When I do that, it seems like the whole where clause is being ignored. If I only use `"status = " + selectedStatus` in clause, the markers are filtered, but no longer refreshes when something changes in the Fusion table.

Comment: but when the where-clause would be ignored you shouldn't get the desired result when you zoom

Comment: @Dr.Molle sorry, I wasn't very clear in my other comment. When zooming in and out displays changes on the map, I'm only using `"status = " + selectedstatus` as the where-clause and not the random clause. I thought that if I combined the two clauses, I'd be able to filter the markers and keep refreshing them. But when I try that, it looks like the clause is being ignored. I tried linking them like this: `"Location != " + randomNumber + " and Status = " + selectedStatus`

Comment: did you try to test the query using the REST-API to be sure that your query is correct?

Comment: @Dr.Molle I checked the query and it didn't work there either, but after changing `Location != randomNumber` to `Location NOT IN(randomNumber)` it did work. After changing my where-clause to `Location NOT IN(randomNumber) AND status = selectedStatus` it worked! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by testing my query with the REST-API. It turns out the "!=" part was causing the problem, after replacing "!=" with "NOT IN()" I was able to filter the markers and keep refreshing them like I wanted to.

The new query looks like this:

```
where: "Location NOT IN('" + (-1 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)).toString() +  "')" + " AND Status = '" + selectedStatus + "'"
```

Thanks for all the help guys.